# How do add together a COUNT() using SUM()?

Tags: mysql, sql

Basically, I have this -

```
SELECT COUNT(student_dormpm.DormCode) * dorm_datapm.DormCharge
FROM student_dormpm
JOIN dorm_datapm
USING (DormCode)
GROUP BY DormCode;
```

with a result of

```
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| COUNT(student_dormpm.DormCode) * dorm_datapm.DormCharge |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                 5250.00 |
|                                                11250.00 |
|                                                 9600.00 |
|                                                 6500.00 |
|                                                 5510.00 |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

But whenever I try to add SUM(), it falls apart and I get an error of  Invalid use of group function.

I've tried this `SUM(COUNT(student_dormpm.DormCode) * dorm_datapm.DormCharge)`

Comment: use `sum(entire query)` not `sum(count) group by`

Comment: @AliSheikhpour Can you elaborate a little bit? Im fairly new to mysql....

Comment: Next time you should show some sample data for your tables and the expected results. You should also tell us what unique keys the tables have. As mentioned in my answer, it seems that `dorm_datapm` is a mere dorm table with `DormCode` being its unique key, but we cannot be sure that is really the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sum` on entire the first query output where an alias name say `t` is specified to the first query output (to simulate a new table) and also an alias say `total` specified to the counter so you can calculate `sum(total)`:

```
select sum(total) as mysum from 
(
SELECT COUNT(student_dormpm.DormCode) * dorm_datapm.DormCharge as total
FROM student_dormpm
JOIN dorm_datapm
USING (DormCode)
GROUP BY DormCode
) t
```

Comment: I don't like this solution. If `DormCode` is unique in `dorm_datapm`, you can simply write `SELECT SUM(dd.DormCharge) FROM student_dormpm sd JOIN dorm_datapm dd USING (DormCode)` without any intermediate grouping. And if it isn't, then you must not multiply with `dorm_datapm.DormCharge`, as this would lead to random results.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Im not sure I completely understand what you're trying to say, but the reason Im multiplying is because Im trying to get the total Revenue of the Dorm by multiplying the number of residents (count of DormCode) with the DormCharge, and then adding them all together with the SUM()

Comment: @Pa3k.m: By joining the two tables, you combine each `student_dormpm` row with its `DormCharge`. So all you have to do is add up all DormCharges. A simple `SUM` without any `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `dorm_datapm` is your dorm table that has one record per `DormCode` with the associated `DormCharge`. (In that case a table name `dorm` ight be more appropriate, though.)

If this is so, then you merely want to sum up the dorm charges:

```
SELECT DormCode, SUM(dd.DormCharge)
FROM student_dormpm sd
JOIN dorm_datapm dd USING (DormCode)
GROUP BY DormCode
ORDER BY DormCode;
```

If, however `dorm_datapm` can have multiple records per `DormCode`, then you'll have to see, whether above query gets you the results you want or if you want to join a `student_dormpm` row with only one `dorm_datapm` row (in which case you would have to extend your join criteria somehow).

If you are only looking for the total, then don't group by `DormCode`:

```
SELECT SUM(dd.DormCharge)
FROM student_dormpm sd
JOIN dorm_datapm dd USING (DormCode);
```